# Como deserializar un XML con varios quiebres Nodos y agregarlos a un modelo

Tags: xml, net, core

estoy en un grave problema tengo el siguiente xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns0:mConsultarServiciosAdqComercioAfiliadoResponse xmlns:ns0="http://localhost/SCTSBJAX/CCE/">
            <ns0:return>
                <sesionRes>
                    <sesionId>7274127</sesionId>
                    <userId>8</userId>
                    <hashSesion>6BE1A09ED5B7A21C3E865F2B33CF6AD73BA2A3DC9CCB61613503441AD006A754</hashSesion>
                    <codTran>-1</codTran>
                    <mensajeError>
                        <numeroError>0</numeroError>
                        <numeroErrorISO>00</numeroErrorISO>
                        <descripcionMensaje>Proceso completado satisfactoriamente</descripcionMensaje>
                        <tipoMensaje>I</tipoMensaje>
                    </mensajeError>
                    <codigoEmpresa>1</codigoEmpresa>
                    <codigoInstitucion>-1</codigoInstitucion>
                </sesionRes>
                <serviciosAdquiriencias>
                    <codigoEmpresaAdq>1</codigoEmpresaAdq>
                    <codigoAplicacionAdq>VEX</codigoAplicacionAdq>
                    <codigoServicioAdq>6</codigoServicioAdq>
                    <debitoCreditoOtro>O</debitoCreditoOtro>
                    <descripcion>CONSULTA DE SERVICIOS</descripcion>
                </serviciosAdquiriencias>
                <serviciosAdquiriencias>
                    <codigoEmpresaAdq>1</codigoEmpresaAdq>
                    <codigoAplicacionAdq>VEX</codigoAplicacionAdq>
                    <codigoServicioAdq>7</codigoServicioAdq>
                    <debitoCreditoOtro>C</debitoCreditoOtro>
                    <descripcion>PAGO DE SERVICIOS</descripcion>
                    <instituciones>
                        <codigoInstitucion>256</codigoInstitucion>
                        <descripcionInstitucion>ABITMEDIA</descripcionInstitucion>
                        <productos>
                            <codAplProducto>SER</codAplProducto>
                            <codigoProducto>21</codigoProducto>
                            <descripcionProducto>COMPRAS EN LINEA</descripcionProducto>
                        </productos>
                        <productos>
                            <codAplProducto>SER</codAplProducto>
                            <codigoProducto>338</codigoProducto>
                            <descripcionProducto>COMPRAS EN LÍNEA DE DIVERSAS EMPRESAS ALIADAS CON ABITMEDIA</descripcionProducto>
<camposAdicionales>capons</camposAdicionales>
                        </productos>
                    </instituciones>
                </serviciosAdquiriencias>
        </ns0:return>
        </ns0:mConsultarServiciosAdqComercioAfiliadoResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

y al tratar de usar XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServicioAdquirencias));

Me da un error que Institucion es muy dificil de deserializar, como puedo recorrerlo con un foreach, a traves de nodos sabiendo que tengo modelos creados en c# con la etiqueta xmlAtributte, XmlRoot
gracias